# Will Using Short-Circuiting in WHERE Clause Improve Speed

Tags: sql, sql-server, short-circuiting

**Use case**: I am going to be using SQL Server to retrieve values from a large table (1,000,000+ rows) where many different columns can be used as filter criteria, some more frequently used than others.

**Questions**

1. Would it be faster to utilize short-circuiting in the `WHERE` clause so that less comparisons are done?
2. Should the most commonly used criteria be filtered first to do even less comparisons?
3. Should the most commonly used criteria be indexed?

**Example**

- No short circuiting

```sql
SELECT value
FROM AssignmentTable
WHERE (criteriaOne = <criteriaOneValue> OR criteriaOne IS NULL)
  AND (criteriaTwo = <criteriaTwoValue> OR criteriaTwo IS NULL)
  AND (criteriaThree = <criteriaThreeValue> OR criteriaThree IS NULL)
  AND ... for all criteria (roughly 15)
```

- With short circuiting

```sql
SELECT value
FROM AssignmentTable
WHERE 1 = 
  CASE
    WHEN (criteriaOne = <criteriaOneValue> OR criteriaOne IS NULL) THEN
      CASE
        WHEN (criteriaTwo = <criteriaTwoValue> OR criteriaTwo IS NULL) THEN
          CASE
            WHEN (criteriaThree = <criteriaThreeValue> OR criteriaThree IS NULL) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
          END
        ELSE 0
      END
    ELSE 0
  END
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean this:  `(criteriaOne = @criteriaOne OR @criteriaOne is null) . . .`?  That is, the *comparison* value is `NULL`, not the data value.

Comment: I was just using <criteriaOneValue> as a place holder this query would be generated with an actual value. I dont want to check if that value is null though, I want to check the value in the column

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR construction instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Erland has an extensive discussion of [dynamic search conditions](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) - still good information though it has a focus on a stored procedure implementation.

Comment: You should not use `CASE` as it guarantees it will make the condition unsargable and remove any hope of using an index, focussing on "less comparisons" is virtually never relevant. You should be focussing on only reading rows necessary for the final result in all cases. If this is a "catch all" query likely this will be a problem as it needs to create an execution plan valid for all cases

Answer (score 1):

The pattern for doing this without dynamic SQL in SQL Server is to use OPTION (RECOMPILE) to prune the un-needed predicates before the query optimizer generates a query plan.

EG:

```
SELECT value
FROM AssignmentTable
WHERE (Column1 = @column1 OR @column1 IS NULL)
  AND (Column2 = @column2 OR @column2 IS NULL)
  AND (Column3 = @column3 OR @column3 IS NULL)
  AND ... for all criteria (roughly 15)
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

See the classic [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) for a complete discussion of the alternatives.